# Je l'ai attendu et je me suis endormi

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical, passé-composé

A. dit à B. qu'il lui parlera après avoir accompli quelques tâches. B. l'attend et, finalement, s'assoupit.

Si B. raconte ce qui s'est passé par la suite, il pourrait dire :

> En l'attendant, je me suis endormi.
>
> Je me suis endormi alors que je l'attendais.
>
> Je l'ai attendu et je me suis endormi.

Est-ce que la troisième phrase est aussi correcte dans ce contexte ? Je pense que oui, mais j'ai des doutes. En tout cas, j'ai l'impression que les deux premières conviennent davantage.

Answer (score 1):

Toutes ces phrases sont grammaticalement correctes. La question est plutôt de savoir celles qui correspondent le mieux à la situation décrite.

Le première ne le fait pas bien, car à partir du moment où il s'est endormi, il n'attendait plus alors que *en l'attendant* décrit une situation qui dure. Ce qui passerait mieux, c'est par exemple *En l'attendant, j'ai regardé une vidéo ma tablette*.

La deuxième correspond bien à ce qui est décrit. J'aurais probablement choisi *pendant que* plutôt que *alors*, mais la phrase peut être retournée comme ceci : *Alors que je l'attendais, je me suis endormi.*

La troisième est très factuelle mais ne situe pas clairement l'endormissement par rapport à l'attente. *Puis* irait mieux : *Je l'ai attendu puis je me suis endormi*.

Comment: A partir du moment où il s'est endormi, il n'attendait plus? Ce ne me paraît pas logique. Alors, on ne pourrait jamais dire: "Je l'attendais en dormant"? "Pas en regardant la télé".

Comment: @Lambie On peut mais si je ne le recommande pas, c'est que le sens habituel d'attendre est incompatible avec le sommeil : TLFi ***Attendre*** : *Rester en un lieu, **l'attention étant fixée** sur quelqu'un ou quelque chose qui doit venir ou survenir.*

Comment: Hmm. Le Larousse dit: 1. ***Rester en un lieu jusqu'à ce que quelqu'un arrive, que quelque chose soit prêt ou se produise*** : Comme le TLFi. Le plus important c'est **rester en un lieu**. Le fait de dormir n'a pas d'importance.

Comment: @Lambie Si si, il faut quand même parfois dormir. Bonne nuit.